# $f_0 = 0$,$f_1= 1$, and $f_n=f_{n-1}$ + $f_{n-2}$, for all $n>=2$. Use mathematical induction to prove

Tags: summation, induction, fibonacci-numbers

$\sum_{i=0}^{2n}(-1)^i f_i = f_{2n-1} - 1$, for any positive  integer n.

1. Let P(n) be $\sum_{i=0}^{2n}(-1)^i f_i = f_{2n-1} - 1$.
2. Basis step P(1) : $\sum_{i=0}^{2}(-1)^i f_i = f_{2*2-1} - 1$.
   1=1 => true.
3. Hypothetical assumption : Assume P(k) is true : $\sum_{i=0}^{2k}(-1)^i f_i = f_{2k-1} - 1$
4. We need to prove that P(k+1) is true: $\sum_{i=0}^{2k+2}(-1)^i f_i = f_{2k+1} - 1$

Here's where I am lost at what to do. I have tried to look at the left hand side to transform the summation into something similar to the assumption but could not find any formula to do that. What should I do to get the proof ?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Where you wrote $1=1\implies$ true, did you mean $0=0$?

Comment: @J.W.Tanner yeah, I actually meant 0=0, in my paper I accidentally used P(2) as my basis step. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Take two terms out of the sum, so you can use the induction hypothesis:

$$\sum_{i=0}^{2k+2}(-1)^i F_i = -F_{2k+1}+F_{2k+2}+\sum_{i=0}^{2k}(-1)^iF_i$$

$$=-F_{2k+1}+ F_{2k+2}+F_{2k-1} - 1=F_{2k}+F_{2k-1}-1=F_{2k+1}-1$$

Comment: most often, I see [Fibonacci numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number) written with a capital *F*

Comment: Thank you! I was thinking to do the same, but could not find any info online that taking terms out of a summation was allowed this way. Also, I understand how you received $-F = (-1)^1F$ and $F= (-1)^2F$ , but how did you receive indexes?  I assume they are not related to $i$ right?

Comment: I'm not sure that I understanding what you're asking in that last comment, but I took the terms for $i=2k+1$ and $i=2k+2$, which are $(-1)^{2k+1}F_{2k+1}$ and $(-1)^{2k+2}F_{2k+2}$ out of the sum, which is justified by the meaning of summation notation, and $i$ here has nothing to do with $\sqrt{-1}$, if that's what you're asking

Comment: It's not a dumb question.  To get the equation on top, I took the last two terms ($i=2k+1$ and $i=2k+2$) out of the summation -- all of the terms from $i=0$ to $i=2k$ remained in the summation.  I could have written it $\left(\sum\limits_{i=0}^{2k}(-1)^iF_i\right)-F_{2k+1}+F_{2k+2}$, but I didn't want to have to bother with parentheses

Comment: Oh, got it. Thank you so much for explaining it in an elaborate and comprehensive way!